# In C++17 should this code be producing warnings?

Tags: c++, c++17, sequence-points

As seen on this godbolt [link](https://godbolt.org/z/sE7czJ)

clang in c++14 mode(but not in c++17) and GCC in c++17 mode produce warnings about sequencing.
I assumed that in C++17 all stuff on the rhs of = is evaluated before lhs so I am not sure if the gcc warning is correct.

```
Code is:
static int index =0; 
void f(int* pindex){
        pindex[index] = 5;
        pindex[index] = index++;

}
int main(){

}
```

gcc warning is:

: In function 'void f(int*)':

> :4:30: warning: operation on 'index' may be undefined
> [-Wsequence-point]
>
> ```
> 4 |         pindex[index] = index++;
>
>   |                         ~~~~~^~
> ```
>
> :4:30: warning: operation on 'index' may be undefined
> [-Wsequence-point]
>
> Compiler returned: 0

note: I know that standard specifies nothing about warnings, it is just much easier to specify the question wrt warnings, than to talk about sequence point/ordering guarantees.

Comment: That exact example is listed on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) as undefined behaviour until c++17. You seem to be right that gcc's warning is incorrect.

Comment: `pindex[index++] = index;` produces the same warning

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code could produce warnings before C++17 where it was undefined behavior, but should not with C++17 or later as the behavior became defined:

> 20. In every simple assignment expression `E1=E2` and every compound assignment expression `E1@=E2`, every value computation and side-effect of `E2` is sequenced before every value computation and side effect of `E1` (since C++17)

([Source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order))

GCC's warning is a bug.  (Hopefully this is the *only* bug and GCC doesn't actually treat this case as UB.)

Comment: accepted, but that cppreference link was useless to me, I just can not parse all that conditional language... I wish I could select the language version so I do not have to parse ifs in my head while trying to learn. :)

Comment: Well, that's why I quoted the relevant section.